# Надо найти максимум значение трехмерного массива

Tags: java, массивы

Код написал, но тут ошибка

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

```
 Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=sc.nextInt();
    int[][][]a=new int[n][n][n];
    int max=0;
    System.out.println("Введите массивы");
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; i++){
            for(int k=0; k<a[i].length; k++){
                a[i][j][k]=sc.nextInt();
                if(max<a[i][j][k])
                    max=a[i][j][k];
            }
            System.out.println("Максимум։ "+max);
        }
    }
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: вбиваем текст `array index out of bounds` в гугл транслейт и получаем: `Индекс массива за пределами границ`.... итого: происходит чтение из индекса ячейки, которой нет...например всего ячеек 5, а попытка взять происходит из 6

Comment: Да я знаю перевод, но как исправить

Comment: не выходить за границы массива очевидно, как же еще

Comment: Брат можешь исправить мой код, мне надо чтобы программа сработало

Comment: так включи отладчик, пройдись им по коду и сам исправь  http://learn.javajoy.net/debug-intellij-idea

Comment: @HaykMkrtchyan for(int k=0;k<a[j].length;k++)

Comment: У меня код сверху норм отработал. При каких условиях у тебя ошибку выдает?

Comment: @LexHobbit for(int k=0;k<a[i][j].length;k++) У тебя упадет, если первый разряд больше второго.

Comment: @flybox, согласен, к тому времени уже взгляд замылился =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В представленном примере минимум 2 ошибки:

1. В строке `for(int j=0; j<a[i].length; i++)` нужно инкрементировать `j`, а не `i`.
2. В строке `for(int k=0; k<a[i].length; k++)` нужно сравнивать `k` не с длиной массива `a[i]`, а с длиной массива `a[i][j]`.

Comment: И ещё int может быть отрицательным, поэтому инициализируем его минимальным целым: int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;